# What is the best way to achieve horizontal drag scrolling in Avalonia UI?

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

How to do horizontal drag scroll in avalonia ui? Can you help me with horizontal scrolling while you are tapping the screen like a phone. It will be used like soft for terminals in markets. You can check my code please:

c# modelview

```
using AvaloniaUI.Services;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using AvaloniaUI.ViewModels;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using AvaloniaUI.Models;
using Avalonia.Controls;


namespace AvaloniaUI.ViewModels
{
    class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public string VARIABLE
        {
            get => "1";
            set => this.VARIABLE = value;
        }
        public MainWindowViewModel(Database db)
        {
            List = new ColorViewModel(db.GetItems());
        }


        public void AddBlock()
        {

        }



        public ColorViewModel List { get; }


    }
}
```

xaml view

```
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="200" d:DesignHeight="300"
             x:Class="AvaloniaUI.Views.CustomUserWindowProfile"
             >


    <!-- Создадим разметку экрана-->
    <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Classes="controler" Content="-">-</Button>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Classes="controler" Content="+">+</Button>
            </Grid>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ItemsControl Items="{Binding List.Items}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Classes="obj"
                                Background="{Binding hexcolor}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Width="200"
                                Height="200"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

i dont know how to do this, because wpf methods are not working. I am ver waiting for your answer please! What way should i use for horizontal tap scrolling in avalonia ui?